# Do I need to reinstall pear and phing when I upgrade from PHP5.3 to PHP5.4 ?

Tags: php, pear, phing

Can I just copy my old pear and phing folders to PHP5.4 folder?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that.

Two reasons:

- PEAR allows packages to modify the package's PHP code during installation, e.g. to put the path of files directly into the code. When moving files, those now hard-coded paths break.
- The PEAR registry and configuration files have full paths in them. Moving the files breaks them.